# Heroku H13 error code! Can someone explain this? What is the difference between connect and service in the heroku error logs?

Tags: django, heroku

I want to post file to heroku, the file that been uploaded is around 40mb,and when uploading  is almost finished error happens:

```
2019-07-31T23:02:47.346551+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/ML/create/" host=myapp.com request_id=2251b038-b0f6-4ecc-b722-13227f1bc2ba fwd="36.72.216.138" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=60006ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=http
```

Comment: My guess is _something_ times out after 60 seconds as hinted by `service=60006ms`. Does it take more than a minute to upload a 40MB file?

Comment: yes it is, the connection here is slow, so basically what is the different between connect and service? @Selcuk